# "Connection refused" Error for Namenode-HDFS (Hadoop Issue)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

All my nodes are up and running when we see using `jps` command, but still I am unable to connect to hdfs filesystem. Whenever I click on `Browse the filesystem` on the Hadoop Namenode localhost:8020 page, the error which i get is `Connection Refused`. Also I have tried formatting and restarting the namenode but still the error persist. Can anyone please help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check whether all your services are running `JobTracker, Jps, NameNode. DataNode, TaskTracker` by running `jps` command.

Try to run start them one by one:

```
./bin/stop-all.sh
./bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
./bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start jobtracker
./bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start tasktracker
./bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
```

If you're still getting the error, stop them again and clean your temp storage directory. The directory details are in the config file `./conf/core-site.xml` and the run,

```
./bin/stop-all.sh
rm -rf /tmp/hadoop*
./bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Check the logs in the `./logs` folder.

```
tail -200 hadoop*jobtracker*.log
tail -200 hadoop*namenode*.log
tail -200 hadoop*datanode*.log
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

HDFS may use port 9000 under certain distribution/build.

please double check your name node port.

Comment: This was my fix for a new Hadoop cluster running with Spark 2.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

Change the core-site.xml

```
   <property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://hadoopvm:8020</value>
     <final>true</final>
   </property>
```

change to the ip adress .

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://192.168.132.129:8020</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```