# Connection refused while starting Hadoop daemons

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh

I have created a Hadoop cluster with 2.6.0 and with following configuration:

- 1 Name node- Name Node, Resource Manager, Secondary Name Node, Hive
- 8 Data nodes - Data Node, Node Manager

After the set up, it was working fine. After 1 day, it started showing errors  shown below:

```
[root@Bigdata-017 ~]# start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
15/10/02 16:20:54 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [Bigdata-017]
Bigdata-017: ssh: connect to host Bigdata-017 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.20: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.20 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.22: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.22 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.21: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.21 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.24: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.24 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.16: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.16 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.18: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.18 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.19: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.19 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.23: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.23 port 9000: Connection refused
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 9000: Connection refused
15/10/02 16:21:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
resourcemanager running as process 2442. Stop it first.
172.16.253.16: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.16 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.18: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.18 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.19: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.19 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.20: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.20 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.21: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.21 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.23: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.23 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.24: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.24 port 9000: Connection refused
172.16.253.22: ssh: connect to host 172.16.253.22 port 9000: Connection refused
```

Only Resource Manager is working fine. But other that, none of the services are running. Please help me on this. I'm struggling a lot to get it fix.

Comment: See if this SO link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883564/hadoop-connection-refused-on-namenode

Comment: as I saw the link which you mentioned it is not the case in my cluster because i deleted all in my /etc/hosts/:
[root@Bigdata-016 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
172.16.253.16   Bigdata-016
172.16.253.17   Bigdata-017
172.16.253.18   Bigdata-018
172.16.253.19   Bigdata-019
172.16.253.20   Bigdata-020
172.16.253.21   Bigdata-021
172.16.253.22   Bigdata-022
172.16.253.23   Bigdata-023
172.16.253.24   Bigdata-024
there is no chance to bind 9000 on localhost.

Comment: i have added 127.0.0.1 localhost to /etc/hosts though its showing same error..

Comment: see if this SO link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630460/connection-refused-error-for-namenode-hdfs-hadoop-issue?rq=1

Comment: I tried...but no use